# How to return errors from a UDF in Firebird?

Tags: firebird

I'm writing a UDF for Firebird that extracts information from a blob and returns it as a string.

If I hit a problem (bad data, or bad parameters to the UDF), is there any way to send an error message/code back to Firebird.

I know I could put a message into the string return value, which the user would see, but Firebird wouldn't recognise that an error occurred.

I'm using Firebird 2.1.

Comment: I have looked at some of the existing UDFs, but I don't see an obvious mechanism, you might want to ask on the firebird-support or firebird-devel mailinglists (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for subscription information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDFs should not raise exceptions because the Firebird engine isn't able to catch them.

[Firebird Release Notes 2.1.4](http://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb20x-udf-nullpointer):

> Since UDFs have no formal mechanism to signal errors, the returned value would have to be used as an indicator.

For example, you can uses **Magic Prefixes** Pattern to return an error information:

- return "!ErrorCode!Error message", if an error occurs;
- return "Result", if all is OK.